# Strange output(square symbol) in the Java code

Tags: java, stack

everyone. I am currently having issue on doing the evaluation of postfix expression in Java and I think everything is alright except the output is not really correct. But never mind, please let me to post all the codes so that all of you can have a look on them. By the way, please be noted that all of you just need to concentrate on TestPalindrome class is enough because I never change the codes for the other classes except the class that I specified just now.

StackInterface defines all the methods that are available to ArrayStack class.

```
      //There is no need to check this.
      public interface StackInterface<T> {
      /** Task: Adds a new entry to the top of the stack.
       *  @param newEntry  an object to be added to the stack */
      public void push(T newEntry);

      /** Task: Removes and returns the stack誷 top entry.
       *  @return either the object at the top of the stack or, if the
       *          stack is empty before the operation, null */
      public T pop();

      /** Task: Retrieves the stack誷 top entry.
       *  @return either the object at the top of the stack or null if
       *          the stack is empty */
      public T peek();

      /** Task: Detects whether the stack is empty.
       *  @return true if the stack is empty */
      public boolean isEmpty();

      /** Task: Removes all entries from the stack */
      public void clear();
    } // end StackInterface
```

ArrayStack class that is nothing special.

```
//There is no need to check this.
public class ArrayStack<T> implements StackInterface<T> {
    private T[] stack;    // array of stack entries
    private int topIndex; // index of top entry
    private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 50;

    public ArrayStack() {
    this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    } // end default constructor

    public ArrayStack(int initialCapacity) {
        stack = (T[]) new Object[initialCapacity];
        topIndex = -1;
    } // end constructor

    public void push(T newEntry) {
        topIndex++;

    if (topIndex >= stack.length) // if array is full,
        doubleArray();              // expand array

        stack[topIndex] = newEntry;
    } // end push

    public T peek() {
        T top = null;

        if (!isEmpty())
            top = stack[topIndex];

        return top;
    } // end peek

    public T pop() {
        T top = null;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            top = stack[topIndex];
            stack[topIndex] = null;
            topIndex--;
        } // end if

        return top;
    } // end pop

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return topIndex < 0;
    } // end isEmpty

    public void clear() {

    } // end clear

    /** Task: Doubles the size of the array of stack entries.
     *        Refer to Segment 5.18 */
    private void doubleArray() {
    T[] oldStack = stack;                // get reference to array of stack entries
      int oldSize = oldStack.length;       // get max size of original array

      stack = (T[]) new Object[2 * oldSize]; // double size of array

      // copy entries from old array to new, bigger array
    System.arraycopy(oldStack, 0, stack, 0, oldSize);
    } // end doubleArray
} // end ArrayStack
```

The following class is TestPalindrome class.(The class name may sounds strange because the exercises that I did were all in the same class and I do not post the irrelevant codes in the class.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPalindrome {

    public TestPalindrome() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //P3Q2

        StackInterface<Character> myStack = new ArrayStack<Character>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int result;
        char resultInChar;

        System.out.print("Please enter a postfix expresion : ");
        String postfix = scanner.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++)
        {
            char postfixChar = postfix.charAt(i);

            if(Character.isDigit(postfixChar)) //If postfixChar is a digit, then it will be pushed into the stack.
            {
                myStack.push(postfixChar);
            }


                 /*(For else statement) First operand will be popped as right operand and second 
operand will be popped as left operand if postfixChar is operator such as + .
The calculation of both operands will be carried out based on the operator given. 
After this the result of calculation will be pushed back into the stack and the 
same things will happen again.*/ 

            else 
            {
                int firstOperand = Character.getNumericValue(myStack.pop()); //To get numeric value of the first character stored. 
                System.out.println("\nThe right operand : " + firstOperand);
                int secondOperand = Character.getNumericValue(myStack.pop()); //To get numeric value of the second character stored.
                System.out.println("The left operand : " + secondOperand);

                switch(postfixChar)
                {
                    case '+':
                        result = secondOperand + firstOperand;
                        System.out.println("The result is " + result);
                        resultInChar = (char)result; //Convert the result of calculation back to character data type so that it can be pushed into the stack.
                        System.out.println("Strange output : " + resultInChar); //Here is where the strange output occurred. 
                        myStack.push(resultInChar);
                        break;

                    case '-':
                        result = secondOperand - firstOperand;
                        System.out.println("The result is " + result);
                        resultInChar = (char)result;
                        myStack.push(resultInChar);
                        break;

                    case '/':
                        result = secondOperand / firstOperand;
                        System.out.println("The result is " + result);
                        resultInChar = (char)result;
                        myStack.push(resultInChar);
                        break;

                    case '*':
                        result = secondOperand * firstOperand;
                        System.out.println("The result is " + result);
                        resultInChar = (char)result;
                        myStack.push(resultInChar);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe answer of " + postfix + " is " + Character.getNumericValue(myStack.pop())); //To get the final answer in the form of numeric value
    }
}
```

Here is the attachment of the picture to show all the outputs of the program.

[image]

Please explain the wrong part as I really cannot figure out why this will happen since 1 + 1 = 2 and the ASCII code of 2 which is 50 should be displayed instead of the weird square symbol.Thanks because spending the valuable time to look into my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> Please explain the wrong part as I really cannot figure out why this
>   will happen since 1 + 1 = 2 and the ASCII code of 2 which is 50 should
>   be displayed instead of the weird square symbol.

Yes, 1 + 1 = 2. But if you cast it to a char, it will use ASCII value 2, and not 50. To do that, you should do something like:

```
resultCharIn = (char) ('0' + result);
```

In other words: `'0' != 0`.

However, this seems like a wrong approach, because: what if the result is greater than 9. You will need two characters. Maybe you should consider a different design?

Comment: I am very glad that this statement resultCharIn = (char) ('0' + result); really gives what I want. On the other hand, thanks for your gentle reminder because without the reminder, I will not be able to notice that there is a flaw in the code. So, I would like to say a thousand thanks to you：）